# How to configure jenkins to read the user mails from poms?

Tags: maven, jenkins, mercurial, maven-3, jenkins-plugins

We have developer sections in our poms:

```
<developers>
  <developer>
    <id>id</id>
    <name>name</name>
    <email>name@company.com</email>
  </developer>
</developers>
```

Is there a way that jenkins uses this emails? The current version already parsed all users by id from their mercurial commits, but doesn't map the mail correctly. I can change that in every user profile manually and the last version of the job owner plugin already respects that manual entry correctly. However this manual setup suc*s. I want jenkins to map this from pom automatically.